# Flutter Stream Builder return only one LisTile from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have a stream builder that is supposed to return a multiple LisTile but it returns only one, I have used the same structure with other collections and its work fine but for this collection it doesn't.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder(
                    stream: DatabaseService().itemsCollection.snapshots(),
                    builder: ( context,  snapshot){
                      if (!snapshot.hasData){  
                       return Loading();
                                          }
                              else{  
                        List<Item> myItems= [];


                        for (int i=0; i<snapshot.data.documents.length; i++){
                          DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.documents[i];

                          myItems.add(
                            Item(
                            restaurantId: snap.data['restaurantId'],
                            id:snap.documentID ?? '',
                            name:snap.data['name']?? '',
                            price:double.tryParse(snap.data['price'].toString())?? 0,
                            calories:double.tryParse(snap.data['calories'].toString())?? 0,
                            section: MenuSection('','',''),
                            imageUrl:snap.data['imageUrl']?? '',
                            describtion: snap.data['describtion']?? '')
                          );


                               return 
                                   ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: myItems.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, i) => Column(
                                    children: [ 
                                      ItemListItem(
                                        id: myItems[i].id,
                                         name: myItems[i].name,
                                         describtion: myItems[i].describtion,
                                         price: double.tryParse(myItems[i].price.toString()),
                                         imageUrl: myItems[i].imageUrl,
                                        // branchId: branchId,
                                         restId: myItems[i].restaurantId ,

                                        ),

                                     // Divider(),
                                    ], ),
                                  );

                        } 
                   }
                   }
            );
```

[Data in FireStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXk5y.png)

If anyone can find where the issue please.

================= UPDATE =================

Issue Solved.

To whom might face this issue later,

I found the issue is that I have put the return statement inside the for loop, while it should after the loop ends!